# Excel hardcode, subnet value that increments

Tags: excel

im currently trying to figure and formula that can help me.

I want to receive a subnet from a costumer Ex(100.100.100.0 or 10.200.200.20)

And incremente based on the value given.

So in the first row it will always be the value given +1 (100.100.100.1 or 10.200.200.21).
Second row  the value given +2 (100.100.100.2 or 10.200.200.22)

And so on.
Last one base value +14(100.100.100.14 or 10.200.200.34)

I wanted this hardcoded(no macro) for the excell sheet , and only change the last octet. Im havig ptrouble as the string size can chage.
This is used to devide the ip in a /28 subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your IP number is in cell `A1`, enter the following array formula in cell `A2`...

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(IF(MID(A1,ROW(1:15),1)=".",ROW(1:15)))-1) & "." & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MAX(IF(MID(A1,ROW(1:15),1)=".",ROW(1:15),0)))+1
```

To confirm the formula be sure to use `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`.

Now copy cell `A2` downward as far as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula you are looking for:
`=CONCATENATE(REPLACE($B$2;13;100;"");ROW(A1)+RIGHT($B$2;LEN($B$2)-SEARCH(".";$B$2;12)))`

And with this input the output should be as shown in the image below:

[image]

The solution concatenates all the characters until the last "." with the sum of the number of the row it is and the number after the last ".".